# Forcing the user to type just Numbers

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I have a TextBox and I want that the user type just numbers, not other format.

How can I do that ?

Comment: If you have access to his keyboard remove the alphabetic keys. Not every solution needs to be software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a regular expression validator:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1"
ErrorMessage="Please Enter Only Numbers" Style="z-index: 101; left: 424px; position: absolute;
top: 285px" ValidationExpression="^\d+$" ValidationGroup="check"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Answer (score 2):

see this thread for a jquery solution 
[How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TexBox runat="server" ID="TexBox1" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ValidationExpression="\d+" ControlToValidate="TexBox1" ErrorMessage="Error!" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input name="number" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')">
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is by using the FilteredTextBox:

> ilteredTextBox is an extender which prevents a user from entering invalid characters into a text box. Note that since this effect can be avoided by deactivating JavaScript, you should use this extender as a convenience for your users, but you must never expect that the data being sent to the server consists of "valid" chars only.

http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx